# Python code to test the Postgres connectivity and get response code

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am working on an AWS Lambda function to test URL connectivity and get respose code. I have used the below code to get it

```
import urllib
from urllib import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib import request, parse

def fn_getresponsecode(url):
    try:
        conn =urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return conn.getcode()
    except HTTPError as e:
        return e.code
    except URLError as e:
        return e.reason

fn_getresponsecode("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Now, I want to test a postgres connection from Lambda function and check if it is getting connected. Is there a way by which we can do that. Also, the password is also not provided.

In unix I have tested it using the code below:

```
pg_isready -h test.test1.region.rds.amazon.com -p port_number -U user_name
```

Comment: This [post](http://josephkokenge.com/2018/12/29/Connect-PostgreSQL-RDS-instance-and-Python-AWS-Lambda-function/) shows how to connect to Postgres RDS from Python, I think you can adapt it to check for connectivity.